# Creating Cassandra sub-clusters

Tags: cassandra, cql, cassandra-3.0

I need to create K overlapping Cassandra clusters on N machines (K>>N). Each cluster can have between 1 to N nodes. I know that one way of doing so is to create a separate process (or docker container) for each cluster a node is a member of.

My question however is that can I change Cassandra to allow the creation of sub-clusters? meaning that there would be only 1 Cassandra instance running on each node, but I would be able to take control of data replication and data placement so that within a sub-cluster for example, I would be able to do a Quorum write for example.

Comment: Could you describe you use case in more detail? A solution might be to use data centers, but I'm not sure if I understood correctly your question.

Comment: So I need to replicate based on use case, so for a specific keyspace or row, I'd like to replicate on certain servers (based on geo-graphic location). For other rows, I'd like to do something else

Comment: For example can I do a quorum write a row onto servers a-b-c (my assumed sub-cluster is: a-b-c-x-y) while for another row do a quorum write on servers b-d-e (sub-cluster is b-d-e-p-q)?

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not possible to define the sub-cluster as you describe - there is always a single Cassandra cluster per process.

But Cassandra has a notion of the [Datacenter](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/6.0/dse-arch/datastax_enterprise/dbArch/archIntro.html#Keystructures) that defines where machine resides, and the keyspace that defines how the data is replicated between datacenters and nodes. And consistency level, like, `QUORUM` depends on the keyspace configuration.

In your case I would think in that direction - define datacenters, create necessary keyspaces, and setup correct replication factors for that keyspaces.

Comment: Using datacenters, can I replicate a row on a certain server while for another row, replicate it somewhere else? 
For example can I do a quorum write a row onto servers a-b-c (my assumed sub-cluster is: a-b-c-x-y) while for another row do a quorum write on servers b-d-e (sub-cluster is b-d-e-p-q)?

Comment: If not, which parts of Cassandra do you think I have to modify to get the desired outcome?

Comment: If this data inside the same table, then it's impossible... But if it's in the different keyspaces, then it's possible if you define DCs correctly...

Comment: Regarding the modification, I think that it's too big change to perform. I recommend to ask in cassandra-user mailing list

Comment: can I ask why you need this?

Comment: I want to have my own replication model that depends on closeness(latency-wise) for individual Datastores and have the ability to dynamically create these sub clusters. A research project

Comment: I suppose I have to probably change the NetworkTopology and also the DynamicSnitch. Is there anything else? (assuming that I want to have custom replication on the level of keyspace not row or table)

Btw I do want my DC's to be dynamic they come and go on the fly

Comment: maybe you can change partitioner as well?